# Azure AD B2C Put newly signed up user in a group

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm evaluating B2C as a replacement for our current identity system. What I can't figure out is how to add a user to a group or groups upon signing up. Is this possible? Do I need to make a second call to the graph api on my end after the signup is complete? If so, how do I know that a user signed up?

Also, is the group options blade in the portal not working for others? It doesn't render for me properly so I can't see all the options or select any of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app will have to add them a group with a call to the Graph API after they sign up.

You can know if they just signed up from the claim **newUser**. You do have to enable this claim for the sign-up policy for it to appear. This claim will have value *true* if the user just finished sign up.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Custom Policies to have a custom sign up page call an API during sign up.

Comment: While this answer is true, most people would probably like to have an example :) I'm not saying include the whole content of 3 XML files, just the key part of making the Azure Function etc. call from the policy.